# Hiding a div once scrolling past a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow that has a height set to auto so any height image can be displayed. Within that slideshow I have two arrows which are wrapped in a div with a class of .center. The arrows are at a fixed position so when scrolling the arrows would follow. The function that is assigned to div="center" will display when you scroll over the div .center.

The problem I am having is once I scroll past the slide show div the arrows are still present. But when I scroll up past my slide show div the arrows are hidden.

How can I set up my script for when I scroll down to div 2 or end of slide show which has a class of cs-slider the center will be hidden?

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".center").each( function() {
      if( $(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 150 ) {
        $(this).css('opacity',1);
      } else {
        $(this).css('opacity',0);
      }
    }); 
 });
```

HTML

```
 <section class="cs-slider" style="margin-bottom: 80px;" >
  <div class="center" id="box" >
      <a href=# id="prev">Prev</a> 
      <a href=# id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
     <div class="slides cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-fx="fade"
        data-cycle-prev="#prev"
        data-cycle-next="#next"
       data-cycle-pager=".pager"
        data-cycle-loader="wait"
        data-cycle-swipe=true
        data-cycle-swipe-fx=scrollHorz
        data-cycle-auto-height=container
        data-cycle-center-horz=true
       data-cycle-timeout="0"
        data-cycle-speed="500"
>
<div class="pager"></div>
  </div>
  </section><!-- slider -->
  <section class="workContent fadeDown"><!-- Hide .center once you scroll over section -->

  </section>
```

CSS

```
 cs-slider .slides  { margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; display:block; z-index:1}
 .cs-slider             { position:relative; text-align:center; padding:4em 0em 1em 0em;}
 .center                    {opacity: 0; }
 #prev, #next               { position:fixed; top: 0%; width: 10%; height: 200px; cursor: pointer; text-indent:-9999px;}
 #prev                      { left: 0;  background: url(http://malsup.github.com/images/left.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; }
 #next                      { right: 0; background: url(http://malsup.github.com/images/right.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;}
 #prev:hover, #next:hover   { opacity: .7; filter: alpha(opacity=70) }
 .disabled                  { opacity: .5; filter:alpha(opacity=50); }
```

Comment: I made a jQuery plugin for this, maybe you can find it useful: https://github.com/DebonairStudios/fromTop.js

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you not want to show any overflow?  If so, try CSS overflow: none;

Comment: I am sorry if it was bit confusing. What I want is the div to be confined in div 1. So when you scroll over div 1 the arrows will display once you scroll over div 1 and now on div 2 I would like to arrows to fadeOut. @IanWise

Comment: I will take a look into your plugin @JacobGray

Comment: your plugin does not work correctly @JacobGray

Comment: What do you mean? what are you trying to do, and what does not work?

Comment: I tried looking at some of your examples and your links are broken. Also when I insert your code into my site it is hiding a completely different div then what I am calling

Comment: You should post your HTML also. Your original request isn't entirely clear, and you won't receive concise answers if people need to make assumptions.

Comment: I forgot about those links >.< are you trying to fade out a div when it reaches the top of the window?

Comment: I just added my HTML @CannonFodder

Comment: I am trying to fade out once I scroll to a specific div which in this case would be . workContent. I only want to display the arrows within a specific div. So if I scroll past or below the arrows fadeOut @JacobGray

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following.

```
$(this).css('display', 'none');
```